# can the splash screen time be configured?

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, rubymotion

I have an app where the first screen user sees has data that is fetched from the server. The app also has a splash screen that shows up when the app is being loaded.

**Problem**
Depending on the users connection time it might take a few seconds for the data to load. In this scenario, the splash screen comes up for few seconds and then I just see a blank (black) screen for another few seconds and then I see the first screen. I suspect the blank screen comes up for the time it takes to fetch data from the server. I looking for ways to solve this issue

**Question**

- Can the length of time the splash screen shows up be configured? For example, maybe the splash screen can stay up till the data is fetched?
- Can some sort of spinner be showed instead of a black blank screen while data is being loaded?

**Update**

This is how I'm loading the data

```
  def self.fetch(client, &block)
    client.shared.headers["username"] = App::Persistence["username"]
    client.shared.headers["token"] = App::Persistence["sessionId"]
    client.shared.get('categories') do |result|
      if result.success?
        ary = result.object
        block.call(ary)
      end
    end
  end
```

and to use it

```
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
      @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
      Color.fetch(AFMotion::Client) do |data|
        main_controller = ColorController.alloc.initWithData(data)
        @window.rootViewController = UINavigationController.alloc.initWithRootViewController(main_controller)
        @window.rootViewController.navigationBar.barTintColor = '#DF533B'.to_color
        @window.rootViewController.navigationBar.translucent = true
        @window.rootViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor
        @window.rootViewController.navigationBar.setTitleTextAttributes({
            UITextAttributeTextColor => UIColor.whiteColor
        })
      end
      @window.makeKeyAndVisible

      @window.tintColor = '#DF533B'.to_color
    end
```

Comment: Add a "waiting" View/ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can, but it should not be done. The "splash" screen is shown when you app is being loaded in memory. You can delay the remove all of this screen bij not return directly form the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. **But doing so might get your app killed by the os because it is take to long to load.**

You best option to place a view in the `UIWindow` that show that your app is downloading data. This way your user see that your app is doing something. If it is possible to show some kind of progress here that would even be better.

You could even do it in the view controller where you perform the network call, just push a loading view onto the view just before you start the netwerk call. Once it is finished remove the view. This will work only if the network call is not blocking any UI updates.

Comment: Thanks..didn't know about restrictions on app store. So, say, I have a simple view with the word "loading" in UIWindow...how can I just show it for the time the data is loaded from the server? I'm using AFNetworking to load the data.

Comment: That totally depends on you code, there is not genic way to do it. And it is not a restriction of the AppStore, iOS will kill apps that do not start in time.

Comment: sounds good. I've updated the question with some code that shows how I'm loading the data and then showing my controller. If it helps further...

Comment: Doing any blocking calls inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions beside setting up the UIWindow is not recommended. I would also suggest not adding a view to the UIWindow but setting the rootViewController to be the loading view instead.

Comment: If I don't do it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` then where should I do it? Is my only option to show a static controller to the user first and THEN load the data from the server?

Comment: @Pete42 Why don't you recommend to a `UIView` to the `UIWindow`? As stated in my answer the best way is to a loading view to view that is doing the request.

Comment: Simply because that is not what it is meant for. You should add your view the the rootViewController on the `UIWindow` or create a separate loading view controller

Comment: @Pete42, true that is a good rule, but create a viewcontroller for a loading dialog is a bit overkill, you could easily just a loading view to the viewcontroller that is performing the call.

Comment: really depends on how you want to structure the code but it is simpler to add it to the main controller since you don't have to add and remove controllers.

Comment: @birdy you might want to check this.  It's old, but good:

http://www.iconoclastlabs.com/blog/iphone-splash-screen-with-rubymotion

Answer (score -1):

The "splash screen" or what you set to Default.png cannot be set to be longer. It is only shown until your app has launched. You are also right in thinking that your app is staying on a black screen because the fetching might take long.

To solve this problem you can do a couple things.

1. Move data fetching to an other thread than the mainThread so that the UI is not locked and then refresh your view once the data has finished downloading. while that is happening you can show a spinner or whatever you want.

```
[self showLoadingView];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    [self doDataFetch];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self hideLoadingView];
        [self reloadView];
    });
});
```

1. Show a different controller at launch in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then download your data in the background and when that is done show the view controller that requires the data.

The takeaway is that you should not do the data fetch on the mainThread. **DO IT IN THE BACKGROUND**. This will prevent the UI from locking and the app taking long to load.

Comment: I am using AFNetworking to fetch the data. That should be doing it in the background by design right?

Comment: I've updated the question with code that shows how I'm loaded data and showing controller

Comment: I know that the objective-c interface usually is since it uses blocks but it would seem like your code doesn't. To me client.shared.get('categories') do |result| if result.success? seems like it would block since it would do the get and then wait for that to finish before doing the if.